# Finding Largest Values in Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to return `arr` with the largest element in each array, however I am receiving an error message. Thanks.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, arr[i]);
    }
}
```

`largestOfFour([1,2,4],[23,22,0])`

> TypeError: second argument to Function.prototype.apply must be an array

Comment: `largestOfFour` expects one argument, whereas you pass two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `map` function

```
array.map(function(array) {
  return Math.max.apply(Math, array)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped out a lot. But how does it know to iterate through both arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you're sending two params to `largestOfFour`, but you should just send one, with an array at each index.

`largestOfFour([[1,2,4],[23,22,0]])`

In order to get the return result you're looking for.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var returnArray = []
  for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    returnArray.push(Math.max.apply(Math, arr[i]));
    }

  return returnArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved one problem. But the iteration is not going through and returning `[4,23]`

Comment: Just made an edit so it returns what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing your function an array of arrays -- you're passing it TWO arrays.  :)

Try this:

```
largestOfFour([[1,2,4],[23,22,0]])
              ^                 ^
```

Additionally, largestOfFour, as defined, returns the max the first time it runs -- in effect, returning the max value of the first array in the array of arrays.

To do it that way, you could save the max each time, then return the max of that.

Or take advantage of join()'s apparent flattening of nested arrays and do this:

```
Math.max.apply(null, a.join().split(','))
```